# Не получается распарсить api с помощью retrofit2

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit2, gson

Пытаюсь распарсить https://favqs.com/api/ с помощью retorfit2
Для начала хочу хотя бы извлечь дату из json

```
@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class Example {

    @SerializedName("qotd_date")
    @Expose
    private String qotdDate;
    @SerializedName("quote")
    @Expose
    private Quote quote;

    public String getQotdDate() {
        return qotdDate;
    }

    public void setQotdDate(String qotdDate) {
        this.qotdDate = qotdDate;
    }

    public Quote getQuote() {
        return quote;
    }

    public void setQuote(Quote quote) {
        this.quote = quote;
    }

}
```

класс Quote:

```
@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class Quote {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("dialogue")
    @Expose
    private Boolean dialogue;
    @SerializedName("private")
    @Expose
    private Boolean _private;
    @SerializedName("tags")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> tags = null;
    @SerializedName("url")
    @Expose
    private String url;
    @SerializedName("favorites_count")
    @Expose
    private Integer favoritesCount;
    @SerializedName("upvotes_count")
    @Expose
    private Integer upvotesCount;
    @SerializedName("downvotes_count")
    @Expose
    private Integer downvotesCount;
    @SerializedName("author")
    @Expose
    private String author;
    @SerializedName("author_permalink")
    @Expose
    private String authorPermalink;
    @SerializedName("body")
    @Expose
    private String body;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Boolean getDialogue() {
        return dialogue;
    }

    public void setDialogue(Boolean dialogue) {
        this.dialogue = dialogue;
    }

    public Boolean getPrivate() {
        return _private;
    }

    public void setPrivate(Boolean _private) {
        this._private = _private;
    }

    public List<Object> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    public void setTags(List<Object> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public Integer getFavoritesCount() {
        return favoritesCount;
    }

    public void setFavoritesCount(Integer favoritesCount) {
        this.favoritesCount = favoritesCount;
    }

    public Integer getUpvotesCount() {
        return upvotesCount;
    }

    public void setUpvotesCount(Integer upvotesCount) {
        this.upvotesCount = upvotesCount;
    }

    public Integer getDownvotesCount() {
        return downvotesCount;
    }

    public void setDownvotesCount(Integer downvotesCount) {
        this.downvotesCount = downvotesCount;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getAuthorPermalink() {
        return authorPermalink;
    }

    public void setAuthorPermalink(String authorPermalink) {
        this.authorPermalink = authorPermalink;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

}
```

интерфейс Client:

```
public interface Client {

    @GET("qotd_date")
    Call<List<Example>> reposForUser(@Path("user") String user);
}
```

класс MyAdapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Example> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Example> values;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Example> values) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item_pagination, values);

        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater =
                    (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_pagination, parent, false);
        }

        TextView textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_item_pagination_text);

        Example item = values.get(position);
        String message = item.getQotdDate();
        textView.setText(message);

        return row;
    }
}
```

класс MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.pagination_list);


        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://favqs.com/api/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

        Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

        Client client = retrofit.create(Client.class);
        Call<List<Example>> call = client.reposForUser("qotd_date");

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Example>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Example>> call, Response<List<Example>> response) {
                List<Example> repos = response.body();

                listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, repos));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Example>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

К сожалению, приложение не работатет, и как это исправить, я не понимаю
При запуске появляется ошибка RuntimeException в строке         `Call<List<Example>> call = client.reposForUser("qotd_date");`

Текст ошибки:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.semenov.retrofitproject, PID: 10813
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.semenov.retrofitproject/com.semenov.retrofitproject.ui.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL "qotd_date" does not contain "{user}". (parameter #1)
        for method GitHubClient.reposForUser
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3450)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3602)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2067)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7697)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:952)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL "qotd_date" does not contain "{user}". (parameter #1)
        for method GitHubClient.reposForUser
        at retrofit2.Utils.methodError(Utils.java:54)
        at retrofit2.Utils.methodError(Utils.java:43)
        at retrofit2.Utils.parameterError(Utils.java:64)
        at retrofit2.RequestFactory$Builder.validatePathName(RequestFactory.java:829)
        at retrofit2.RequestFactory$Builder.parseParameterAnnotation(RequestFactory.java:416)
        at retrofit2.RequestFactory$Builder.parseParameter(RequestFactory.java:325)
        at retrofit2.RequestFactory$Builder.build(RequestFactory.java:206)
        at retrofit2.RequestFactory.parseAnnotations(RequestFactory.java:67)
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(ServiceMethod.java:26)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:202)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:160)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
        at $Proxy2.reposForUser(Unknown Source)
        at com.semenov.retrofitproject.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8017)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8001)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1310)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3423)
            ... 11 more
```

Также, скорее всего, я не правильно реализовал interface Client:

```
public interface Client {

    @GET("qotd_date")
    Call<List<Example>> reposForUser(@Path("user") String user);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текс ошибки из метода onFailure:

```
W/System.err: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1562)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.checkLenient(JsonReader.java:1403)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:592)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:424)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:74)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:40)
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:27)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:243)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:153)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:174)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Comment: Покажите ошибку целиком. Также покажите как должен выглядеть запрос к апи - какой путь, парамеры, метод. Пока лишь можно предположить, что вам надо что-то такое добавить: ` @GET("qotd_date/{user}")` но это совсем не точно.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я пока только начинаю разбираться с retrofit, поэтому по поводу пути, параметров и метода, пожалуйста, поподробнее

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, "user" возможно, вообще не нужен, я нашёл эту строку кода в интренете, но как приспособить её к моим нуждам пока до конца не сообразил

Comment: Ну... Попробуйте вообще без аргумента тогда, судя по доке к апи - он и не нужен: `Call<List<Example>> reposForUser();`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, приложение запустилось, но в listview ничего не отобразилось

Comment: Для начала проверьте, что у вас что-то пришло с сервера. Выведите в логи переменную repos

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, начал debug, программа доходит до строки call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Example>>() {, но то, что в { } не выполняет

Comment: Чтобы дебаггером пользоваться - надо много знать, уметь, быть в этом (в дебаггинге) профи. Я вот, например, никогда его не использую, хотя уже много лет в профессии. Попробуйте таки просто в логи что-то вывести.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, при запуске приложения в лиги ничего не выводится
// размещение логиов я добваил в скрине в текст вопроса

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, скорее всего проблема в обращении к классу Example в строке call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Example>>() {

Comment: У вас нет логов в onFailure колбэке. Может у вас там ошибка? Выведите ошибку в логи оттуда. Типа так, хотя бы: `t.printStacktrace();`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, t.printStacktrace(); в onFailure добавил, текст ошибки добавил в вопрос

Comment: Попробуйте рекомендацию из текста ошибки выполнить. Коли не поможет - надо искать ошибку в моделях для парсинга JSON

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, попробовал, но пока до конца не понимаю как. Из тех решений, которые я нашёл, некоторые просто не работают, некоторые создают новые ошибки, некоторые я не понимаю, как реализовать

Comment: Покажите как пробовали. И какие ошибки получали. Также можно попробовать локализовать проблему. Если она в моделях - удалите весь код из классов моделей и добавляйте по одной переменной - возможно так что-то заработает и вы сможете понять в какой момент ломается. Возможно станет понятно и почему.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, как оказалось, дело было в том, что не нужно было использовать List, при работе с получаемыми данными. Ваши комменитарии мне тоже очень помогли. Пожалуйста, оформите их в виде ответа, чтобы я мог его принять

Comment: Вы можете сами ответ написать - у меня не будет в ближайшие дни времени(